# Creating classes in Python for Tkinter Labels

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I built an application with Tkinter that displays statistics to labels based on what team is entered in a textbox. The application works, but my code is 600 lines long, most of which is initializing the labels. The majority of labels share the same format (create a label variable, create a label, position the label with grid), so I figured there should be a way that I can make a constructor class that will return me a new variable with a few parameters. Unfortunately I've so far been unsuccessful due mostly to the fact that I have little OOP design experience. What would be the best way to go about this? The following are the two main sections of code I'd like to replace:

```
self.team2RecordlabelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
team2Recordlabel = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.team2RecordlabelVariable,anchor='e', fg='white', bg="black")
team2Recordlabel.grid(column = rColLStart, row = 1, columnspan = colRSpan, padx=(2,10), pady=(1,20), sticky = 'E')
```

and

```
team2RL = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Record: ",anchor='e', fg='white', bg="black")
team2RL.grid(column = rColStart, row = 1, columnspan = colLSpan, padx=(2,0), pady=(1,20), sticky = 'W')
```

Comment: Why are you using a `StringVar` for each label?

Comment: Could you provide more code for context?

Comment: The following is a trace of code following each label:

`# Sets up textbox`
` ...`
`#Set up enter button`
`...`
`#Sets up label`
`self.team1RecordlabelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()`
`team1Recordlabel = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.team1RecordlabelVariable,anchor='e', fg='white', bg="black")`
`team1Recordlabel.grid(column = lColRStart, row = 1, columnspan = colRSpan, padx=(2,10), pady=(1,20), sticky = 'E')`

    ... 

    # After text entered in box and button pressed, update label
    self.team1RecordlabelVariable.set(GrabTeamRecord(htmlTeam1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class if you just want to create a custom label, but IMO if you also want to call `grid` it's better to use a function. IMHO a widget should never call `grid`, `pack` or `place` on itself, since that limits how you use it.

Since you want to create the label and call `grid` at the same time, a simple helper function is all you need. In my example I'm also assuming you don't really need a `StringVar` for each label since you don't show any code that requires it.

```
def create_label(parent, text, row, column, colspan):
    label = Tkinter.Label(parent, text=text, anchor='e', fg='white', bg="black")
    label.grid(column = column, row = row, columnspan = colspan, padx=(2,10), pady=(1,20), sticky = 'E')
    return label
...
self.team2Recordlabel = create_label(self, "", 1, rColLStart, colRSpan)
```

Comment: I use the StringVars in a later function call. Specifically, when a button is pressed, my program updates the labels with information it retrieves from a website. But thank you very much for showing me how to do this.

Comment: @JoshuaLaney: you don't need `StringVars` in order to update a label. They double the number of objects you're managing for no gain. You can directly modify the label itself -- `self.team2Recordlabel.configure(text="foo")`

Comment: interesting and very useful. Thanks for the tip

Comment: If you do use a StringVar then there is no need to keep/catch the return from Tkinter.Label() i.e. use the return from StringVar() instead so you only have one set of objects.

Comment: @CurlyJoe: right -- you either keep the reference to the widget, or keep the reference to the StringVar. Since you already have the widget there's no point in creating an extra object to do something the object you already have can do. Whether you keep two references or not (the StringVar and the label), you still have two objects living in your system when you only need one. From a practical standpoint it's moot since the memory use is negligible, but anytime you can reduce the amount of objects, and code to manage the objects, the less complex your code will be.